# Packaging dependencies for run in Hadoop

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

As a former Java developer who is very familiar with Maven dependencies and packaging... how do you bundle an application and it's dependent JAR's for deployment into a Hadoop cluster? Almost every example I've seen looks at packaging a single JAR. Seems like I'm either missing something.

The -libjars answer given [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/) seems okay for simple dependencies hierarchies but would be almost unmanageable for complex scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, will put forward an answer of how I'm thinking about doing it but let the community decide if this holds water (will mark correct the answer with most points after a week or so).

Previously I've created maven configurations to build executables - usually these create an exploded folder with all dependent JAR's and a batch script which contains all dependencies concatenated together (automatically)... I think that might be the best option.

Zipping those up and pushing into a central maven repo might be easiest for packaging but would still need to be downloaded and unzipped before running on Hadoop.